# Angular dynamically listen for modal attribute and perform action

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I have a toolbox component with buttons - pen, line, arrow, hand and delete. Delete button is disabled by default. With pen, line and arrow I can draw on canvas component below toolbox. Hand selects the drawn object and also enables delete action. When clicking on delete, the modal dialog will appear with possibility to delete or cancel. There is also other possibilities to close this dialog - esc, clicking away and X button.
When I close the modal by clicking on "delete" or cancel", the focus will go back to the hand, but when I close the modal by other options - esc, clicking away or X, the focus will stay on delete button and I can not reopen the modal even though the delete button stays enabled.
The solution is to click on hand and again on delete.
This modal also has the attribute opened.

Is there any way I can dynamically listen to this attribute and when the modal is closed, just set:

```
document.getElementById('toolbox-hand').click();
```

toolbox html - items

```
<button (click)="selectItem("pen")">Pen</button>
<button (click)="selectItem("line")">Line</button>
<button (click)="selectItem("arrow")">Arrow</button>
<button (click)="selectItem("hand")">Hand</button>
<button (click)="selectItem("delete")">Delete</button>
```

toolbox ts

```
public selectItem(item: string): void {
  // toolboxService.selectedItem - this is in service set to "hand" by default
  if (this.toolboxService.selectedItem === item) {
  // setting focus to that element
  } else {
  this.toolboxService.selectedItem = item;
  }
}
```

Modal html:

```
<div id="confirmation_modal">
  <p>Modal text</p>
<button (click)="delete.emit(false)">Close</button>
<button (click)="delete.emit(true)">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Modal ts

```
export class ModalComponent {
  @Output() delete: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Canvas (parent) html:

```
<app-modal
  (delete)="delete($event)"
></app-modal>
```

Canvas (parent) ts:

```
public delete(isDelete: boolean): void {
    // delete functionality
    document.getElementById('toolbox-hand').click();
    // close modal functionality
  }
```

Comment: could you please add dialog code?

Comment: Hi @Fseee, I added the code.

Comment: where is the "opened" attribute located?

Comment: In the <div id="confirmation_modal">

Comment: I now tried to solve this issue with defining ```@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) ```where I am checking for attribute "opened" and based on that I perform ```document.getElementById('toolbox-hand').click();``` and it works :) But there could probably be also better solutions :)

Comment: so far so good then

Comment: I now disabled all the buttons by always selecting hand when performing click event :)) My solution above is therefore wrong.